# Adding Values to Nested Dictionary

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

Currently I'm trying to add values into a nested dictionary using VB. I have it working for a flat dictionary, but can't quite get my head around the syntax for doing it nested.

What I have so far is, I have commented the lines I'm having trouble with:

```
Public Shared Dim dictionary AS New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Integer))

Function addValue(ByVal code AS String, ByVal cust AS String,ByVal value AS Integer)
    Dim innerDict AS New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    innerDict.Add(cust,value);
    IF dictionary.ContainsKey(code) Then
            IF dictionary.Item(code).ContainsKey(cust) Then 'Can I access the Customer key in this way? 
                    dictionary.Item(code).Item 'Here I need to update the value held by customer to the old value + new value. 
                Else    
                 dictionary(code).Add(cust,value)  'Is this syntax correct? 
            End If

        Else
            dictionary.Add(code,innerDict)
    End If
End Function
```

What I want to happen is to have a dictionary structured as follow:

```
 Code1:
      Customer1: 12
      Customer2: 13
    Code 2:
      Customer1: 12
      Customer2: 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function that will do what you want.

The first thing it does, is checks whether an entry exists for `code` in `dictionary`. If none exists, it adds one whose value is an empty dictionary that will receive the `cust`-`value` pairs.

Currently the function does not return any value. If no value is to be returned, you should use a `Sub`.

```
Function addValue(ByVal code As String, ByVal cust As String, ByVal value As Integer)

    ' If no entry for code, create one.
    If Not dictionary.ContainsKey(code) Then
        dictionary.Add(code, New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Integer))
    End If
    ' Add cust, value to entry at code.
    dictionary(code).Add(cust, value)

End Function

' Returns sum the customer's values.
Function SumCustomerValues(customer As String) As Integer
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    For Each d As KeyValuePair(Of String, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Integer)) In dictionary
        If d.Value.ContainsKey(customer) Then
            sum += d.Value(customer)
        End If
    Next
    Return sum
End Function
```

Comment: That seems to be doing what I want it do, but how do I access the values within inner dictionary? 

Like this: 

    `dictionary(code).Item(cust)`

I also need to sum the values associated with a code and customer

Comment: @Ualati I added a function to sum the values of a `Customer`. Yes, to access inner dictionary, you can use `dictionary(code).Item(cust)` or `dictionary(code)(cust)`, but you need to check that `code` and `cust` entries exist otherwise exception is thrown.

Comment: I didn't realise in the first function a single customer entry is added which is great, but I am using the dictionary as a running total.

(I know this isn't ideal, but SSRS has weird rules with getting totals) 

In the version of my dictionary which wasn't nested I had the following code to update the value everytime a new one was added.

`IF dictionary.ContainsKey(cust) Then
 dictionary(cust) = dictionary.Item(cust) + value
     Else
         dictionary.Add(cust,value)
    End If`

Comment: My "solution" would be to do something like this 

`If Not dictionary.ContainsKey(code) Then
        dictionary.Add(code, New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Integer))
    Else 
        If dictionary(code).ContainsKey(cust) Then
            dictionary(code)(cust) = dictionary(code).Item(cust) + value
        End If
    End If`